# Using Pattern Matching in Prolog to Find Submultisets

Tags: list, prolog, pattern-matching, prolog-setof

I am new to prolog and I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem.  The problem:  given the integers 1,2,3,4, and the predicates mult/2, div/2, div/2, minus/2, and minus/2, and eval/2, I need to write a predicate solutions/1 that, when called like this:

```
?- solutions(L).
```

it should terminate with the variable L unified to a list of expressions with value 6.  Expressions are of the form:

```
X, Y, exp/2
```

But my code is not working.  I have two versions.  The first freezes up SWI-Prolog, not returning any answer after I type a period, and not letting me evaluate anything else afterward:

```
eval(1,1.0).
eval(2,2.0).
eval(3,3.0).
eval(4,4.0).

eval(mult(X,Y),Z) :-
    eval(X,A),
    eval(Y,B),
    Z is A*B.

eval(div(X,Y),Z) :-
    eval(X,A),
    eval(Y,B),
    Z is A/B.

eval(minus(X,Y),Z) :-
    eval(X,A),
    eval(Y,B),
    Z is A-B.

solutions(L) :-
    setof(X,eval(X,6),L),
    print(L).
```

The second version just returns false when I type `?- solutions(L).`:

```
solutions(L) :-
    setof([exp,X,Y],eval(exp(X,Y),6),L),
    print(L).
```

Thank you so much for taking the time to help!

Comment: First version doesn't freeze but got into an infinite loop due to recursion that won't terminate. `eval` calls `eval` endlessly since you're missing the logic for it to terminate. You could try `trace.` and run your query again and you'll see after several steps where it starts to repeat itself. In the second version, in the code you're showing, I see no way for `eval(exp(X,Y), 6)` to succeed since there's no fact or predicate head that matches. `exp` isn't shown anywhere.

Comment: @lurker thanks for the feedback!  That makes sense; I was pretty sure that it wouldn't be able to find `exp` anywhere, but I didn't know how else to pattern match to the predicates mult/2, div/2, etc.,. as this is my very first time coding in prolog.  If you have any suggestions about how to do that, please lmk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like

```
solutions(L) :-
    Ns = [1,2,3,4],
    Ex = [*,/,-],
    findall((X,Y,E),
       (member(X,Ns),member(Y,Ns),member(E,Ex),F=..[E,X,Y],6=:=F),
       L).
```

that yields

```
?- solutions(L).
L = [(2, 3,  (*)),  (3, 2,  (*))].
```

Expressions are usually recursive, that is, arguments could be expressions instead of plain numbers. But then, in my opinion your problem is underspecified, as we *need* criteria to stop the infinite flow of solutions resulting - for instance - by repeated application of operations that don't change the value. Like multiply or divide by 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is going in infinite recursion with eval/2 predicate.

You can try this solution:

```
num(1).
num(2).
num(3).
num(4).

eval(mult(A,B),Z) :-
    num(A),
    num(B),
    Z is A*B.

eval(div(A,B),Z) :-
    num(A),
    num(B),
    Z is A/B.

eval(minus(A,B),Z) :-
    num(A),
    num(B),
    Z is A-B.

test(L) :-
    setof(X,eval(X,6),L),
    print(L).
```

Which yields:

```
?- test(L).
[mult(2,3),mult(3,2)]
L = [mult(2, 3), mult(3, 2)].
```

Comment: Hi @Sahil thanks for the answer!  I just tried this, and it won't compile.  I think because there is no base case for eval/2...

Comment: @Maclafel7 : Check the updated code. This is what I get on compiling the code.